# Problem on probability expectation value

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability

I have go through a lesson of classical probability and it is the no. of trial divided by the total number. And I have already read the three types of probability distribution such as Binomial distribution, Poisson distribution, and last but not least the normal or Gaussian distribution. In all this distribution I read a term called expectation value of probability distribution of which is termed as $E(x)$.
I know that the expectation value means the mean value of $x$ for the given distribution. Now I just come across Expectation of $x^2$ which is denoted as $E(x^2)$ but I don't know the physical significance of this term.
But if I take an  example say Maxwell velocity distribution law which is generally a normal distribution of no. of particles corresponds to velocity range $c$ to $c+dc$,in this distribution expectation value of $c^2$ or $E(c^2)$ refer the square value of R.M.S velocity

So what does actually mean by $E(x^2)$ from probabilistic sense??

And similarly we can also establish $E(x^3)$,$E(x^4)$,$E(x^5)$,.........

So what do all this terms signifies in physics? As I only know $E(x)$ means average value of $x$.

Comment: The integral *E(x)* is the *average value* of an *infinite* number of measurements of the *position* of the particles that are prepared in the same state described by the same wavefunction.
*E(x^n)* is the expectation value of a *function of position, x^n* that can be interpreted as an average of the mathematical function *x^n*

Comment: @Benjamin: How did you make the leap from stochastics to quantum mechanics???

Comment: I am trying to see if I can formulate the response into a classical one. Somehow I assumed that talking about "states" and "infinities" would make it easier to understand. But, your are right; there should not be such assumption.

Comment: I am dealing with classical probability

Comment: So what is the esence of E(x^2)in physics??

Comment: By x, do you actually mean position? or velocity? or any general physical quantity?

Comment: I have to leave now but will be back and follow the post.

Comment: I mean position

Comment: But I use an example of Maxwell's distribution in which probability is about velocity